# How does Java dereferencing work?

Tags: java, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I need to get some clarification on Java references (pointers).
I have read this ([Java is Pass-by-Value, Dammit! by Scott Stanchfield](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)) excellent write up on Java's way of passing variables around. As far as I understand everything is passed around as memory pointers.

```
public class foo{
    int a;
    int b;

    public foo(a, b){
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
    }
}
```

so in some code like this:

```
foo aFoo = new foo(1,2); //new foo created at adress 0x40 for instance
someFunc(aFoo);
```

the argument to `someFunc`is actually the number `0x40` (albeit this might be a simplification, but to get a sense for the pattern).

Now, suppose i created another class

```
public class bar{
    foo aFoo;

    public bar(){
       this.aFoo = new foo(1,2);
    }
}
```

and instantiated the following variables

```
bar aBar = new bar();
foo bFoo = new foo(3,4);
```

now suppose i want to copy the values of `aBar.aFoo` into `bFoo` like

```
bFoo = aBar.aFoo;
```

If i now do

```
bFoo.a = 1234;
```

did i also just change `aBar.aFoo.a` into 1234 or does that variable still hold the value `1`?

By my own logic, `bFoo.a` is just a pointer, so assigning a new variable should alter both places, but this seems incorrect. So I guess i have not fully understood Java's "reference is really a pointer" concept. Or rather, i might understand the pointer part of it, but not the dereferencing of the pointers, since this is done implicitly compared to in C where you always know.

Comment: "did i also just change aBar.aFoo.a into 1234 or does that variable still hold the value 1?" Try it and see.

Comment: They're not pointers, they're *references*. This is a very, very important difference. When you assign using ``=``, you're assigning a new *reference* to the variable, not a new *value*. This is why your assumption fails; When you do ``bFoo.a = 1234`` you're creating a reference to a new value, ``1234``, then replacing the current reference in ``bFoo.a`` with the new reference. The reference in ``aBar.aFoo`` is complete unchanged.

Comment: @aruisdante One does not create a reference to a primitive value.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Sorry, you're technically correct, I'm still thinking in python land. The observable behavior is the same, even if the particular optimization is different (java allowing direct access to primitive values rather than going through a reference). The same thing would happen to a non-primitive value as well. But I think I actually slightly missred the OP's question, because it does look like they are aliasing (assigning two names to the same object), in which case changing a member of that object should change the value at both aliases.

Comment: @aruisdante You are also wrong about "the reference in `aBar.aFoo` is completely unchanged". Since `bFoo` is the same as `aBar.aFoo`, this cannot be true.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik See my updated comment. ``foo bFoo = new foo(3,4);`` had confused me, I had read it as ``bFoo.a = aFoo.a``, which would make the values the same, but not link them as the OP would expect due to my original explanation in the case of objects, and Java's assign-by-value for primitive types. Indirection through aliasing (in both Java and Python) is the only way to get equivalent behavior to C++'s ``int *`` which seems to be what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @aruisdante: "They're not pointers, they're references." A "reference" is defined as a pointer to an object. So they are pointers.

Comment: @newacct no, they are not. They are very similar and closely related, but [they are not the same thing](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195337/is-there-any-difference-between-pointers-and-references)

Comment: @aruisdante: No, they are. The word "reference" is a general term that means a general concept. However, the word "reference" has a specific meaning in Java, which is pointer to an object. This is how the word is defined in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bFoo = aBar.aFoo;
```

-> you have assigned the `aBar.aFoo` reference to `bFoo` local variable. This is called *aliasing* because now you have two ways to refer to the same object: `bFoo` and `aBar.aFoo`.

```
bFoo.a = 1234;
```

-> you have assigned 1234 to the `a` field of the object referred to by `bFoo`. This object is referred to by `aBar.aFoo` as well.

Result: you have changed the value of `aBar.aFoo.a`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems I did understand it after all then. But how would I "copy" the value from aBar.aFoo into bFoo, so that they are not linked by reference and that i am free to change bFoo without affecting aBar.aFoo?

Comment: You have met the notoriously difficult problem of object copying (cloning). It doesn't have a general solution.

Comment: Java provides a standard interface to it via [``clone()``](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29), however as @MarkoTopolnik points out what that method does is entirely up to the implementer as there is no general solution to what a 'clone' means for any particular object. And ``clone`` has many limitations for exactly this reason.

Comment: Ok, but as long as we're dealing with simple structures that the one in my example, `bFoo = aBar.aFoo.clone();` would work straight out of the box, right?

Comment: You'd still need to override `clone()`---and not mess anything up while doing so :) `@Override public foo clone() { return (foo) super.clone(); }`